# D3JS: I'm not being able to iterate an array

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to append some text below several charts(like a caption) Using D3JS. In order to so I tried to appended a "g" element and inside it a "text" element, and then tried to access the array of "text" elements  via jQuery to set the html using this route:

```
$("#pie"+ i).find("text:nth-child(4)").eq(1)
```

, which points to the "text" below each donut chart, and using a for loop I tried to set certain text stored in a array of strings, but I'm not able to iterate through the array of "text" elements. Can you tell me what am I going wrong?

This is what I tried to do but didn't work:

```
   g.append("text")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0,60) scale(.7)")
        .attr("class","caption")

    var captionArr = ["chart 1","chart 2","chart 3","chart 4","chart 5","chart 6","chart 7","chart 8"]    

    for(i = 1; i <= $(".caption").lenght; i++){
     ($("#pie"+ i).find("text:nth-child(4)").eq(1)).html(captionArr[i])
    }
```

Here's my Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/jcrr1985/q2uxs8r1/6/

thanks for the help, I appreciate so much.

Comment: you misspelled "length" in your loop

Comment: Could you post JS/HTML/CSS code snippet (Ctrl-M in editor) or codepen/jsfiddle with reproducible example?

Comment: why do this in jQuery when you can do it in d3 and it will work. Just filter the select you get back from d3 on the 4th child with `i%4==0` or `(i+1)%4==0`

Comment: hint: your variable `i` is globally available (add `var` or `let` to change its scope)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jcrr1985/q2uxs8r1/6/

This is the fiddle with the working demo but it doesn't show the text below the charts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 main issues with your code:

1. The main issue is that you're appending `text.caption` to every `<g>` within the SVG which results in `$('.caption').length === 16` which is not what I think you need as you're trying to add 1 label (caption) per chart. If that's not the case, please let me know and I'll edit the post.
2. You're trying to change the texts before the charts are drawn. So you gotta move the `for` loop below the `draw` calls

   To fix #1 above, here's the relevant change needed (append to the `svg` rather than `g`):

   ```
   svg.append("text")
     .attr("transform", "translate(0,60) scale(.7)")
     .attr("class", "caption");
   ```

**Approach 1 using jQuery:**

```
for (var i = 1; i <= $(".caption").length; i++) {
  $("#pie" + i).find("text.caption").html(newarr[i-1]); // as array index starts from 0
}
```

```js
 var myGroup = '<g><path class="st0" d="M15.6,10.9c1.3,0,2.4-1.2,2.4-2.7c0-1.5-1.1-2.7-2.4-2.7c-1.3,0-2.4,1.2-2.4,2.7C13.2,9.7,14.2,10.9,15.6,10.9L15.6,10.9z"/><path class="st0" d="M18.6,11.6h-1.2l-1.8,5.5l-1.8-5.5h-1.2c-1.3,0-2.4,1.2-2.4,2.7v13h2.4l1.2,16.4h3.6l1.2-16.4H21v-13C21,12.8,19.9,11.6,18.6,11.6L18.6,11.6z"/><path class="st0" d="M31.9,10.9c1.3,0,2.4-1.2,2.4-2.7c0-1.5-1.1-2.7-2.4-2.7c-1.3,0-2.4,1.2-2.4,2.7C29.5,9.7,30.6,10.9,31.9,10.9L31.9,10.9z"/><path class="st0" d="M39.8,25.2l-3.6-11.6c0,0-0.6-2-2.4-2h-3.6c-1.8,0-2.4,2-2.4,2l-3.6,11.6l1.2,0.7l4.2-9.5l-3.6,14.3h3.6l1.2,13h2.4l1.2-13H38l-3.6-14.3l4.2,9.5L39.8,25.2L39.8,25.2z"/></g>';

 var data1 = [50, 50];
 var data2 = [70, 30];
 var data3 = [16, 84];
 var data4 = [12, 88];
 var data5 = [29, 71];
 var data6 = [15, 85];
 var data7 = [12, 88];
 var data8 = [10, 90];
 var newarr = ["chart 1", "chart 2", "chart 3", "chart 4", "chart 5", "chart 6", "chart 7", "chart 8"]

 var width = 150,
   height = 150,
   radius = (Math.min(width, height) / 2.8);

 function drawDonut(data, divchart) {
   var sym = "%"

   var color = ["#BC204B", "#00338D"];

   // sort data
   //data = data.sort(function (a, b) { return b-a; });
   var pie = d3.pie()
     .sortValues(null) // both null means NO sort
     .value(function(d) {
       return d
     })(data);

   var arc = d3.arc()
     .outerRadius(radius - 10)
     .innerRadius(radius - (radius / 1.9));

   var labelArc = d3.arc()
     .outerRadius(radius - 31)
     .innerRadius(radius - 31);

   var svg = d3.select(divchart)
     .append("svg")
     .attr("width", width)
     .attr("height", height)
     .append("g")
     .attr("transform", "translate(" + 75 + "," + 75 + ")");

   var g = svg.selectAll("arc")
     .data(pie)
     .enter().append("g")
     .attr("class", "arc");


   function easeInverse(ease) {
     return function(e) {
       var min = 0,
         max = 1;
       while (max - min > 1e-3) {
         var mid = (max + min) * 0.5;
         emid = ease(mid);
         if (emid > e) {
           max = mid;
         } else {
           min = mid;
         }
       }
       return max;
     }
   }
   var inverseCubic = easeInverse(d3.easeCubic);
   var oneOver2Pi = 1.0 / (2 * Math.PI);
   var total_msec = 2000;

   g.append("path")
     .style("fill", function(d, i) {
       return color[i];
     })
     .transition()
     .ease(d3.easeLinear)
     .delay(function(d) {
       return total_msec * inverseCubic(d.startAngle * oneOver2Pi);
     })
     .duration(function(d) {
       return total_msec * (inverseCubic(d.endAngle * oneOver2Pi) - inverseCubic(d.startAngle * oneOver2Pi));
     })
     .attrTween("d", arcTween);

   function arcTween(d) {
     var i = d3.interpolate(inverseCubic(d.startAngle * oneOver2Pi), inverseCubic(d.endAngle * oneOver2Pi));
     return function(t) {
       d.endAngle = 2 * Math.PI * d3.easeCubic(i(t));
       return arc(d);
     }
   }

   g.append("g")
     .attr("transform", "translate(-17,-17) scale(0.7)")
     .html(myGroup);

   g.append("text")
     .attr("transform", "translate(-10,-55) scale(1)")
     .attr("class", "st0")
     .html(data[0] + "%");


   svg.append("text")
     .attr("transform", "translate(0,60) scale(.7)")
     .attr("class", "caption");
 }


 drawDonut(data1, "#pie1")
 drawDonut(data2, "#pie2")
 drawDonut(data3, "#pie3")
 drawDonut(data4, "#pie4")
 drawDonut(data5, "#pie5")
 drawDonut(data6, "#pie6")
 drawDonut(data7, "#pie7")
 drawDonut(data8, "#pie8")

/* By the code below I'm trying to append some text below each chart, but something's wrong with it*/
 for (var i = 1; i <= $(".caption").length; i++) {
   $("#pie" + i).find("text.caption").html(newarr[i-1]);
 }
```

```css
        div {
          display: inline;
        }

        .st0 {
          fill: #00338D;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Donut man-woman</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>

    <body>
      <div id="pie1"></div>
      <div id="pie2"></div>
      <div id="pie3"></div>
      <div id="pie4"></div>
      <div id="pie5"></div>
      <div id="pie6"></div>
      <div id="pie7"></div>
      <div id="pie8"></div>
      <div id="pie9"></div>
    </body>
```

**Approach 2 using d3 which will mess up on selection update:**

```
d3.selectAll('text.caption').text(function (d, i) { 
  return newarr[i];
});
```

```js
 var myGroup = '<g><path class="st0" d="M15.6,10.9c1.3,0,2.4-1.2,2.4-2.7c0-1.5-1.1-2.7-2.4-2.7c-1.3,0-2.4,1.2-2.4,2.7C13.2,9.7,14.2,10.9,15.6,10.9L15.6,10.9z"/><path class="st0" d="M18.6,11.6h-1.2l-1.8,5.5l-1.8-5.5h-1.2c-1.3,0-2.4,1.2-2.4,2.7v13h2.4l1.2,16.4h3.6l1.2-16.4H21v-13C21,12.8,19.9,11.6,18.6,11.6L18.6,11.6z"/><path class="st0" d="M31.9,10.9c1.3,0,2.4-1.2,2.4-2.7c0-1.5-1.1-2.7-2.4-2.7c-1.3,0-2.4,1.2-2.4,2.7C29.5,9.7,30.6,10.9,31.9,10.9L31.9,10.9z"/><path class="st0" d="M39.8,25.2l-3.6-11.6c0,0-0.6-2-2.4-2h-3.6c-1.8,0-2.4,2-2.4,2l-3.6,11.6l1.2,0.7l4.2-9.5l-3.6,14.3h3.6l1.2,13h2.4l1.2-13H38l-3.6-14.3l4.2,9.5L39.8,25.2L39.8,25.2z"/></g>';

 var data1 = [50, 50];
 var data2 = [70, 30];
 var data3 = [16, 84];
 var data4 = [12, 88];
 var data5 = [29, 71];
 var data6 = [15, 85];
 var data7 = [12, 88];
 var data8 = [10, 90];
 var newarr = ["chart 1", "chart 2", "chart 3", "chart 4", "chart 5", "chart 6", "chart 7", "chart 8"]

 var width = 150,
   height = 150,
   radius = (Math.min(width, height) / 2.8);

 function drawDonut(data, divchart) {
   var sym = "%"

   var color = ["#BC204B", "#00338D"];

   // sort data
   //data = data.sort(function (a, b) { return b-a; });
   var pie = d3.pie()
     .sortValues(null) // both null means NO sort
     .value(function(d) {
       return d
     })(data);

   var arc = d3.arc()
     .outerRadius(radius - 10)
     .innerRadius(radius - (radius / 1.9));

   var labelArc = d3.arc()
     .outerRadius(radius - 31)
     .innerRadius(radius - 31);

   var svg = d3.select(divchart)
     .append("svg")
     .attr("width", width)
     .attr("height", height)
     .append("g")
     .attr("transform", "translate(" + 75 + "," + 75 + ")");

   var g = svg.selectAll("arc")
     .data(pie)
     .enter().append("g")
     .attr("class", "arc");


   function easeInverse(ease) {
     return function(e) {
       var min = 0,
         max = 1;
       while (max - min > 1e-3) {
         var mid = (max + min) * 0.5;
         emid = ease(mid);
         if (emid > e) {
           max = mid;
         } else {
           min = mid;
         }
       }
       return max;
     }
   }
   var inverseCubic = easeInverse(d3.easeCubic);
   var oneOver2Pi = 1.0 / (2 * Math.PI);
   var total_msec = 2000;

   g.append("path")
     .style("fill", function(d, i) {
       return color[i];
     })
     .transition()
     .ease(d3.easeLinear)
     .delay(function(d) {
       return total_msec * inverseCubic(d.startAngle * oneOver2Pi);
     })
     .duration(function(d) {
       return total_msec * (inverseCubic(d.endAngle * oneOver2Pi) - inverseCubic(d.startAngle * oneOver2Pi));
     })
     .attrTween("d", arcTween);

   function arcTween(d) {
     var i = d3.interpolate(inverseCubic(d.startAngle * oneOver2Pi), inverseCubic(d.endAngle * oneOver2Pi));
     return function(t) {
       d.endAngle = 2 * Math.PI * d3.easeCubic(i(t));
       return arc(d);
     }
   }

   g.append("g")
     .attr("transform", "translate(-17,-17) scale(0.7)")
     .html(myGroup);

   g.append("text")
     .attr("transform", "translate(-10,-55) scale(1)")
     .attr("class", "st0")
     .html(data[0] + "%");


   svg.append("text")
     .attr("transform", "translate(0,60) scale(.7)")
     .attr("class", "caption");
 }


 drawDonut(data1, "#pie1")
 drawDonut(data2, "#pie2")
 drawDonut(data3, "#pie3")
 drawDonut(data4, "#pie4")
 drawDonut(data5, "#pie5")
 drawDonut(data6, "#pie6")
 drawDonut(data7, "#pie7")
 drawDonut(data8, "#pie8")

  d3.selectAll('text.caption').text(function (d, i) { 
    return newarr[i];
  });
```

```css
        div {
          display: inline;
        }

        .st0 {
          fill: #00338D;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Donut man-woman</title>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>

    <body>
      <div id="pie1"></div>
      <div id="pie2"></div>
      <div id="pie3"></div>
      <div id="pie4"></div>
      <div id="pie5"></div>
      <div id="pie6"></div>
      <div id="pie7"></div>
      <div id="pie8"></div>
      <div id="pie9"></div>
    </body>
```

**Better approach:**
Pass arguments or index to `drawDonut`.

After moving all data arrays to a single object named `dataObj`, calling `drawDonut` the following way:

```
Object.keys(dataObj).forEach(function (d, i) {
  drawDonut(dataObj[d], '#pie'+(i+1), i, 'chart ' + (i+1));
});
```

where the index is being passed and also the chartName as the 4th argument (use which ever one you feel is convenient) and the texts would get the texts by:

```
svg.append("text")
   .attr("transform", "translate(0,60) scale(.7)")
   .attr("class", "caption").text(chartName || newarr[index]);
```

```js
 var myGroup = '<g><path class="st0" d="M15.6,10.9c1.3,0,2.4-1.2,2.4-2.7c0-1.5-1.1-2.7-2.4-2.7c-1.3,0-2.4,1.2-2.4,2.7C13.2,9.7,14.2,10.9,15.6,10.9L15.6,10.9z"/><path class="st0" d="M18.6,11.6h-1.2l-1.8,5.5l-1.8-5.5h-1.2c-1.3,0-2.4,1.2-2.4,2.7v13h2.4l1.2,16.4h3.6l1.2-16.4H21v-13C21,12.8,19.9,11.6,18.6,11.6L18.6,11.6z"/><path class="st0" d="M31.9,10.9c1.3,0,2.4-1.2,2.4-2.7c0-1.5-1.1-2.7-2.4-2.7c-1.3,0-2.4,1.2-2.4,2.7C29.5,9.7,30.6,10.9,31.9,10.9L31.9,10.9z"/><path class="st0" d="M39.8,25.2l-3.6-11.6c0,0-0.6-2-2.4-2h-3.6c-1.8,0-2.4,2-2.4,2l-3.6,11.6l1.2,0.7l4.2-9.5l-3.6,14.3h3.6l1.2,13h2.4l1.2-13H38l-3.6-14.3l4.2,9.5L39.8,25.2L39.8,25.2z"/></g>';

 var dataObj = {
   data1: [50, 50],
  data2: [70, 30],
  data3: [16, 84],
  data4: [12, 88],
  data5: [29, 71],
  data6: [15, 85],
  data7: [12, 88],
  data8: [10, 90]
  };  
 var newarr = ["chart 1", "chart 2", "chart 3", "chart 4", "chart 5", "chart 6", "chart 7", "chart 8"]

 var width = 150,
   height = 150,
   radius = (Math.min(width, height) / 2.8);

 function drawDonut(data, divchart, index, chartName) {
   var sym = "%"

   var color = ["#BC204B", "#00338D"];

   // sort data
   //data = data.sort(function (a, b) { return b-a; });
   var pie = d3.pie()
     .sortValues(null) // both null means NO sort
     .value(function(d) {
       return d
     })(data);

   var arc = d3.arc()
     .outerRadius(radius - 10)
     .innerRadius(radius - (radius / 1.9));

   var labelArc = d3.arc()
     .outerRadius(radius - 31)
     .innerRadius(radius - 31);

   var svg = d3.select(divchart)
     .append("svg")
     .attr("width", width)
     .attr("height", height)
     .append("g")
     .attr("transform", "translate(" + 75 + "," + 75 + ")");

   var g = svg.selectAll("arc")
     .data(pie)
     .enter().append("g")
     .attr("class", "arc");


   function easeInverse(ease) {
     return function(e) {
       var min = 0,
         max = 1;
       while (max - min > 1e-3) {
         var mid = (max + min) * 0.5;
         emid = ease(mid);
         if (emid > e) {
           max = mid;
         } else {
           min = mid;
         }
       }
       return max;
     }
   }
   var inverseCubic = easeInverse(d3.easeCubic);
   var oneOver2Pi = 1.0 / (2 * Math.PI);
   var total_msec = 2000;

   g.append("path")
     .style("fill", function(d, i) {
       return color[i];
     })
     .transition()
     .ease(d3.easeLinear)
     .delay(function(d) {
       return total_msec * inverseCubic(d.startAngle * oneOver2Pi);
     })
     .duration(function(d) {
       return total_msec * (inverseCubic(d.endAngle * oneOver2Pi) - inverseCubic(d.startAngle * oneOver2Pi));
     })
     .attrTween("d", arcTween);

   function arcTween(d) {
     var i = d3.interpolate(inverseCubic(d.startAngle * oneOver2Pi), inverseCubic(d.endAngle * oneOver2Pi));
     return function(t) {
       d.endAngle = 2 * Math.PI * d3.easeCubic(i(t));
       return arc(d);
     }
   }

   g.append("g")
     .attr("transform", "translate(-17,-17) scale(0.7)")
     .html(myGroup);

   g.append("text")
     .attr("transform", "translate(-10,-55) scale(1)")
     .attr("class", "st0")
     .html(data[0] + "%");


   svg.append("text")
     .attr("transform", "translate(0,60) scale(.7)")
     .attr("class", "caption").text(chartName || newarr[index]);
 }


 Object.keys(dataObj).forEach(function (d, i) {
   drawDonut(dataObj[d], '#pie'+(i+1), i, 'chart ' + (i+1));
  });
```

```css
        div {
          display: inline;
        }

        .st0 {
          fill: #00338D;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Donut man-woman</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>

    <body>
      <div id="pie1"></div>
      <div id="pie2"></div>
      <div id="pie3"></div>
      <div id="pie4"></div>
      <div id="pie5"></div>
      <div id="pie6"></div>
      <div id="pie7"></div>
      <div id="pie8"></div>
      <div id="pie9"></div>
    </body>
```

And there are other approaches too but I think one of these might help you out for now. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do:

```
drawDonut(data1, "#pie1", "Chart 1")

...

function drawDonut(data, divchart, chartName) {
  ...
  g.append("text")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,60) scale(.7)")
    .attr("class", "caption")
    .text(chartName);
}
```